# Supremum, infimum, powerset...

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given the set $S = \{a, b, c, d\}$, and the powerset $P(S)$ of $S$.

The set-inclusion relationship is denoted with $⊆$. In the ordered set $(P(S), \subseteq)$:

$\sup_{P(S)}(\{a, c\}, \{a, d\}) = \{a,c,d\}$ ?

$\inf_{P(S)} (\{a, c\}, \{a, d\}) = \{\{a\},\{c\},\{d\}\}$ ?

Given $A = \{X \in P(S): | X | \le 2\}$. How many and what are the elements of $A$?

Please help me. What does $A = \{X \in P(S): | X | ≤ 2\}$ mean? Are my $\sup$ and $\inf$ correct?

Comment: $A$ is the family of elements of the power set, i.e. the family of subsets of $S$, that contain at most two letters.

Comment: Set-theory often uses $|X|$ to denote the number of members of $X$ when $X$ is finite, and to denote the cardinal of $X$ when $X$ is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is the family of elements of the power set, i.e. the family of subsets of $S$, that contain at most two letters. You should find all subsets of $S$ of this form and count how many they are.

> Post scriptum: in general, if $|S| = n$, and if $A_k := \{X \in P(S)\ |\ |X| \leq k\}$, then $$|A_k| = \sum_{j=0}^k\binom n j$$

Comment: So $A$ has 11 elements?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: The minimal element and minimum of $A$ is $\{Ø\}$?

Comment: No: it is $\varnothing$, the empty set. What you wrote is the set containing only the empty set (the power set of the empty set), which is *not* the empty set itself.

Comment: Aren't $a$,$b$ and $c$ minimal elements too?

Comment: Those are elements of the set $S$, not of its power set. You are studying a partial order defined on the power set $P(S)$.

Comment: $\{a\}$ is a $\subset$-lower bound for $\{\{a,c\},\{a,d\}\}.$

Comment: @giobrach So minimal element = ∅
minimum = ∅
maximal elements = don't exist (?)
maximum = doesn't exist (?)

Comment: I’m sorry OP, I was mistaken concerning the bounds. I removed the wrong part of my answer. My apologies. Remember that $\inf$ is the *greatest lower bound* and $\sup$ is the *least upper bound* according to you partial order, in this case $\subseteq$.

Comment: In any case, you should know that both the $\inf$ and the $\sup$, as in general all the upper and lower bounds, are going to be elements of $P(S)$. If your candidate g.l.b. or l.u.b. do not fit this description, then they are not correct.